# Watir webdriver

Tags: selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I've been using the Watir webdriver for a while now and out of the blue I'm getting the following error:

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError

unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

when trying to set text and other functions.

The script worked fine yesterday... so something has gotten updated and stopped working.  I've already tried updating the chromedriver to the latest one, but am still getting the error.

chrome=65.0.3325.146
chromedriver=2.31.488774

ActionView::Template::Error (unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64)):

```
12:     browser.goto 'www.ANYURL.com'
13:     browser.text_field(id: 'inputs-newEmail').set @keyword.email
```

Has anyone seen this issue before? I'm on a MacBook Pro High Sierra 10.13.3

Thanks

Comment: What fixed it for me was using the chromedriver-helper.  By running 'chromedriver-update 2.36', it linked the latest chromerdriver binary to watir.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 65 is only supported by ChromeDriver 2.36 - see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads:

- ChromeDriver 2.36 - Supports Chrome v64-66
- ChromeDriver 2.35 - Supports Chrome v62-64

Therefore, you will need to update your ChromeDriver version to 2.36.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (unknown error: call function result missing 'value' (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64)):
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.31*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.31*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Supports Chrome v58-60**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.31*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.9**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [**ChromeDriver v2.36**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.36 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Chrome*.
- Execute your `@Test`.